# Is there a Postgres admin GUI that can execute a master file containing multiple sql files

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm developing a really long script. I'd like to break the script into smaller, more manageable scripts and include each sql file in a master file, then just execute the master file.

example: `master.sql`

contents (I don't know the syntax to use):

```
file1.sql
file2.sql
file3.sql
```

I've found several tutorials about using `psql -f` in the command-line and `\i` to include these files, but the preference here is to avoid the terminal and use a GUI to manage my database and execute the `master.sql` script.

Is this possible in any postgres admin GUI? Presumably it's **not** in pgAdmin.

Comment: You can edit your SQL files in any editor (there are much better options than pgAdmin) and then only run a single command in psql (say `psql -f master.sql`).

Comment: OK, then I will be clear: you presumably can't do that in pgAdmin.  Anyway, I can't really see why this is a problem (I may be too used to this limitation).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. And you'll be able to see that it _is_ a problem without a solution if you attempt to do what I want in pgAdmin. It may be a limitation (WADU) of pgAdmin, as you say, so I'll edit my question to open it up to asking for **ANY** postgres GUI that will do this.

Comment: SQL Workbench/J can do that: http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/wb-commands.html#command-wbinclude

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. I noticed in the URL referenced that: _"If the included SQL script contains SELECT queries, the result of those queries will not be displayed in the GUI"._ My scripts have many select statements. To confirm this disclaimer, I tested this product using the WbInclude command on a very simple script containing a select and confirmed it doesn't display the results. I wonder why? Anyway, aside from that, this product definitely works at calling other scripts within scripts.

Comment: What you want is a "plan", sqitch or bash script can do that. I don't know any GUI that do that though.

Comment: [Community Guide to PostgreSQL GUI Tools](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools)

Comment: @jbits what operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A `psql` script

A psql script can index multiple files, let's assume `01_mydb.psql`, is in the current working directory, and you have a directory `01` that has the files `01_schema.sql` and `02_types.sql`.

`01_mydb.psql` may look like this.

```
\i 01/01_schema.sql
\i 01/02_types.sql
```

Or however you want to structure it. If things get more complex and need more order, add more subdirectories

```
\i 01/10_tables/01_foo.sql
\i 01/10_tables/02_bar.sql
```

Then you would just either..

1. Add an index file in `01`, something like `./01/10_tables.psql`
2. Or, just add them all to `01_mydb.sql`

I'll show the second method using `find`,

### Using `find` to generate a master-load script.

Let's go ahead and create that structure.

```
01/
├── 01_schema.psql
├── 02_types.psql
└── 10_tables
    ├── 01_foo.psql
    └── 02_bar.psql
```

Here is the commands we use to create it.,

```
mkdir 01
touch 01/01_schema.sql
touch 01/02_types.sql
mkdir 01/10_tables
touch 01/10_tables/01_foo.sql
touch 01/10_tables/02_bar.sql
```

Now you can use `find` to generate a load script

```
find ./01/ -type f -printf '\\i %p\n' | sort | tee master.psql
\i ./01/01_schema.sql
\i ./01/02_types.sql
\i ./01/10_tables/01_foo.sql
\i ./01/10_tables/02_bar.sql
```

Now just run `master.psql`;

```
psql -d database -f master.psql
```